# Divs on the bottom of a sticky (fixed) navigation bar are not visible

Tags: html, css, menu, sticky

I've created a sticky navigation bar that resizes when scrolling down.
In this navigation bar I created one relative (parent) div called `header_wrap` containing two absolute (child) divs. When doing this the content of those child divs is not visible anymore.

When removing the option `position: relative;` from the parent div `header_wrap` the content of the child divs  become visible however at that moment they ignore the given width of 970px in the header_wrap.

I created a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/wvUWR/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you are absolute positioning elements inside of a parent with no specified height. set `#header_wrap` to `height: 100%;`.